# add count (.length) each items in option on v-select

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to add count `course.length` from api to each item `option` on `v-select` and show data to active based filter.

**For example :** Items in `v-select` contains options `all(count)`, `passed(count)` which filtered from `online.passed`, `not complete(count)`
which filtered from `online.complete`, etc.

**vue.js template :**

```
<template>
  <v-select
    v-model="filter"
    :items="items"
  ></v-select>
  <v-card v-for="online in onlineCourse" :key="online.id">
    <v-card-title>{{online.title}</v-card-title>
    <p v-if="online.complete === 100">{{online.complete}}%</p>
    <p v-else-if="online.complete < 100 && online.complete > 0">{{online.complete}}%</p>
    <p v-else>{{online.complete}}%</p>
  </v-card>
</template>
<script>
  data () {
   return {
     onlineCourse: [],
     filter: 'All',
     items: [
      'All',
      'passed',
      'not complete',
     ],
   }
 }
 method: {
   async getDataOnline () {
    try {
      const request = await Axios.get('v1/courses')
      this.onlineCourse = request.courses
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
   }
 }
</script>
```

**Response JSON :**

```
 "courses": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "title1",
        "passed": false,
        "completed": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "title2",
        "passed": true,
        "completed": 100
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "title3",
        "passed": false,
        "completed": 50
    }
],
```

Answer (score 0):

**Few Observations in current code you posted :**

- You are checking for `online.complete === 100` but you don't have `complete` property in online object. Hence, corrected that to `completed` instead of `complete`.
- closing braces is missing from `online.title` expression.

**Now coming to the original problem :**

To achieve the counts in the `v-select` options. You have to convert your items array from `array of elements` to `array of objects`.

```
items: ['All', 'passed', 'not complete']
```

to

```
items: [{
        name: 'All',
        count: this.onlineCourse.length
      }, {
        name: 'passed',
        count: this.onlineCourse.filter((course) => course.passed)
      }, {
        name: 'not complete',
        count: this.onlineCourse.filter((course) => course.completed === 0)
      }]
```